# Using AWS Athena, Apache Access Log cannot be analyzed as desired

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, analysis, amazon-athena

The current SQL to create a table is as follows.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apache_logs(
  client_ip string,
  client_id string,
  user_id string,
  request_received_time string,
  client_request string,
  server_status string,
  returned_obj_size string,
  referrer string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE
   'com.amazonaws.glue.serde.GrokSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'input.format'='^%{IPV4:client_ip} %{DATA:client_id} %{USERNAME:user_id} %{GREEDYDATA:request_received_time} %{QUOTEDSTRING:client_request} %{DATA:server_status} %{DATA: returned_obj_size} %{DATA:referrer}'
   )
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
    's3://s3-bucket/logs/';
```

If you run the following SQL command on the table above, values ​​that do not fit into the column are added as shown below.

```
SELECT * FROM apache_logs;
```

[image]

The format of the log is below!

```
178.247.80.196 - - [23/Jan/2022:15:21:25 +0900] "POST /app/main/posts HTTP/1.0" 200 5006 "http://hicks.com/blog/tags/home.asp" "Opera/8.83.(X11; Linux i686; ia-FR) Presto/2.9.162 Version/10.00"
```